# Vertical alignment floater div method not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the floater div (http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) method of vertically centring a h2. It doesn't work with the markup I have (see example below):

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/LCP5K/1/

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why use the floater div method over say the line-height method?

Comment: It is a responsive design and text being dynamic can spill into 2 lines, setting the line height to the size of the container won;t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand if you were trying to put that text box in the centered div or not , you didn't have it that way in your html, THis is an example of how to center with the method you were talking about , although there are much better ways , that is probably why this one was the last option of those examples in that link  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCP5K/7/)